# Enumerating to infinity in more than two dimensions

Tags: c#, algorithm, loops, enumeration

If I want to enumerate over all combinations of *multiple bounded* values, it's easy enough:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= iMax; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j <= jMax; j++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k <= kMax; k++)
        {
            DoSomething(i,j);
        }
    }
}
```

Likewise, if I want to enumerate over a *single unbounded* value, checking for some condition, that's easy enough too:

```
BigInteger i = 0;
while(true)
{
    if(Condition(i)) { break; }
    i++;
}
```

But what about enumerating over all combinations of *multiple unbounded* values? For two, one way I'm aware of is to "zig-zag", like so:

```
BigInteger i = 0;
BigInteger j = 0;
bool direction = true;
while(true)
{
    if(Condition(i,j)) { break; }

    if(direction)
    {
        if(j==0)
        {
            direction = false;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            direction = true;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

The first few (`i`,`j`) pairs this will produce are: (0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,1), (2,0), (3,0), (2,1), (1,2)...

So my question is: how could this- or some other method- be adapted for more than two dimensions? e.g. If I want to loop over `i`, `j`, and `k`?

**Note:** I'm aware that there are better ways to write these examples, I've just written them as plainly as possible for simplicity.

Comment: you get one enumerating 2-tuples now you just have to see that there is a very simple one-to-one correspondence between `(x,y,z)` and `((x,y),z)` ;I

Comment: This kind of depends on what the break condition is, and what you know about it. You need to avoid a case where you head off in some direction and never hit the break point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(limit=0;;++limit) {
  for(i0=0; i0<=limit; ++i0) {
    for(i1=0; i1<=limit-i0; ++i1) {
      for(i2=0; i2<=limit-i0-i1, ++i2) {
        for(i3=0; i3<=limit-i0-i1-i2, ++i3) {
          int i4 = limit-i0-i1-i2-i3;
          //do stuff with i0, i1, i2, i3, i4; break when had enough
      }}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2D: generate all pairs (j, k) such that j+k==i, for increasing i.

```
for (i= 0; true; i++)
  for (j= 0, k= i; 0 <= k; j++, k--)


i=0 -> (0, 0)
i=1 -> (0, 1), (1, 0)
i=2 -> (0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)
...
```

In 3D: generate all triples (j, l, m) such that l+m==j for increasing j, and j+k=i, for increasing i.

```
for (i= 0; true; i++)
  for (j= 0, k= i; 0 <= k; j++, k--)
    for (l= 0, m= j; 0 <= m; l++, m--)


i=0, j=0 -> (0, 0, 0)
i=1, j=0 -> (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0)
i=1, j=1 -> (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0)
i=2, j=0 -> (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 0)
i=2, j=1 -> (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 0)
i=2, j=2 -> (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 0)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So, one dimension is easy, as you mentioned.  Just count up from zero.

Two is also not that hard, just count along a diagonal:

```
11
7    12
4    8    13
2    5    9    14
1    3    6    10    15
```

For three dimensions we can imagine a pyramid, in which we add a new shell each time:

Here, the numbers are going to represent the height at that position, not the order each item is added.

```
1
```

---

```
1
2    1
```

---

```
1
2    1
3    2    1
```

You can imagine this 3 dimensional diagram as adding shells around a sphere (but moved to a discrete, not continuous, scale), the 2 dimensional version as concentric circles, and the 1 dimensional version as the radius of those concentric circles.  Of course in all cases we have just 1/4 the picture, since you're limiting everything to positive values.

So, how do we do this in the nth case.

Well, each shell is represented by each combinations of values for each dimension such that their sum is some constant.  So first you find every combination of natural number values for each dimension such that their sum is `1`, then you find all of the combinations that sum up to `2`, then you find all of the combinations that sum up to 3, and you go on to infinity.

Answer (score -1):

This is truly a combinatorics problem, not a computer programming problem.

In any case, you can approach this unbounded multivariable problem this way:

`At level 0, you have 1 problem to check [0,0,0]
At level 1, you have 3 problems to check ([0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0])
At level 2, you have 6 problems ([0,0,2],[0,2,0],[2,0,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0])`

so you've got to generate all possiblities (recursion can help) for each level

Comment: The question is clearly about a procedure to enumerate all combinations.